# Why do we need Dijkstra's algorithm if this simpler, faster algorithm works?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have an an algorithm that iterates via BFS the whole graph, and it will update the score to find the min values to all nodes. And I believe the runtime complexity of this is O(V+E), which I believe is better than Dijkstra. Now obviously I'm not naive enough to actually think this algorithm is correct. However, I'm curious in which case, this would not find the optimal min path. here is the code I have

```
from queue import Queue

ad_list = {
    'A': {'B': 1, 'D': 3},
    'B': {'A': 1, 'D': 1, 'C': 5},
    'D': {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 3},
    'C': {'B': 5, 'D': 3}
}

min_weights = {
    'A': 0,
    'B': float('inf'),
    'C': float('inf'),
    'D': float('inf'),

}


def fake_dijkstra(ad_list):
    queue = Queue()
    queue.put('A')

    visited = {}

    global min_weights

    while not queue.empty():
        key = queue.get()

        # update score
        children = ad_list[key]

        for child_key, value in children.items():
            if min_weights[child_key] > min_weights[key] + value:
                min_weights[child_key] = min_weights[key] + value

        if key in visited:
            continue

        visited[key] = True

        children = ad_list[key]

        for child_key, value in children.items():
            queue.put(child_key)


fake_dijkstra(ad_list)
print(min_weights)

# for this case, it correctly finds the min weight to all nodes
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 5, 'D': 2}
```

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. I love algorithms :).

Comment: Why do you use `ad_list[key][child_key]` in your inner loop (twice) instead of just using `value`? I found that confusing.

Comment: oops, you're right! fixed now.

Comment: Note that `queue` is functioning as a stack. I usually replace `while queue: key = queue.pop()` with `for key in queue:`, neglecting to explicitly pop elements.

Comment: Great point david, just fixed it with queue.pop(0) :)

Comment: Why is the line, `children = ad_list[key]`, repeated a second time? ` Note that `global min_weights` could be replaced with `min_weights` as a parameter since it is an object reference.

Comment: @RexAex that works too but is slow (work linear in the size of the queue for each pop).

Comment: @davidEisenstat, thanks for bringing that to my attention. Just realized with python 3, we have this wonderful queue class, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/queue.py, which uses deque.popleft and give o(1) pop runtime :). So gonna start using that from now on. Also modified the original source code :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is not *O(|V|+|E|)*.

Consider a fully connected graph *G(V,E)*, where each node is connected with every other node.

In your algorithm, you are adding each node of such a graph to the queue *|V-1|* times, the startnode is added to the queue *|V|* times. Thus, the total number of elements ever been on the queue is *|V| x |V-1| + 1*

For each element of the queue, you are iterating over all of its *|V-1|* children for checking the minimum weight.

Thus the total number of of steps is *|V| x |V-1| x |V-1|* which is of course *O(|V|³)*

Depending on the data structure used for the queue, Dijkstra's algorithm ranges from *O(|V|² + |E|)* down to *O(|V| x log |V| + |E|)*. For a fully connected graph *|E| = |V|²*, thus Dijkstras algorithm is *O(|V|²)*

So it seems your algorithm can find the shortest paths for a given graph (I'm not 100% sure, but couldn't find a counter example). But it's not a typical BFS, because you are reevaluating the children of a node multiple times. That's also the difference to Dijkstra's algorithm. Because at the time, the children of a node X are evaluated (ie you take the step from X -> Y), it's guaranteed, that there is no shorter path from A to X. Thus, it's in a lower *O-complexity*

Comment: derpirscher, thanks for the elaborate answer! Makes perfect sense now!

Comment: I have a graph in my answer where the algorithm produces the wrong answer, in case you're curious. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef not like the algorithm is currently implemented. OP assumes that if `'A': { 'B' : 5}` is part of the graph, also `'B': { 'A': 5}` must be part of the graph. You can see that in his initial example graph. Which leads to the situation that for instance in step 2 of your description not only `C` is added to the queue, but also `A` and `F`. And for each item on the queue the weight of its children are reevaluated again. Thus the algorithm leads to the expected result (as OP states in the comment) but at a much higher complexity than Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @templatetypedef And that assumption also makes sense, because Dijkstra's algorithm is defined for undirected graphs, ie you may traverse edges in any direction.   I also was thinking for quite a while on "how on earth could this algorithm produce the correct result for this graph" as OP insisted, But then i looked at the original example again and added all the edges in reverse direction as well. And voilà it did output the shortest distance. For instance if there was an edge A -- 1 --> C in your example, the shortest path from A to B will be A -> C -> B

Answer (score 2):

In unweighted graphs, a BFS is indeed the right tool to get distances. However, in weighted graphs, where edges have different lengths, it fails. Construct yourself a graph where there are two paths from a node s to a node t: one path with few nodes, and heavy edges, the other (shorter) one with many nodes and light edges. See what your algorithm does.

Comment: It turns out it's a bit tricky to construct a counterexample because the algorithm will update everything one hop away from all the nodes it revisits, so you have to make the loop a bit longer than expected to introduce an appropriate time delay and then make the path leaving that loop longer than expected in order for the local updates not to correct the initial wrong path.

Comment: I just tried the example Dharman provided, and it worked as well :(. Now i'm very confused. For Dharman the result I got back was {'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 4, 'D': 5, 'E': 1, 'F': 2}

Comment: This is not a typical BFS because the algorithm is "stepping back up" again. Ie  adding nodes to the queue and reevaluate the weight of their children multiple times. This may lead to the correct result, but increases complexity dramatically, especially for dense graphs, where it's *O(|V|³)*

Answer (score 2):

Consider this graph:

```
 A --- 5 --> B --- 1 --> C --- 1 ---> D
 |           ^
 |           |
  
 1           1

 |           |
 v           |
 E --- 1 --> F
```

The shortest path from A to D is found by going A -> E -> F -> B -> C -> D for a total distance of five. However, your algorithm is not guaranteed to find this. Imagine the following happens:

First, we process node A. This marks the distances to B and E as 5 and 1, respectively, and enqueues B into the queue, then E. The queue is now [B, E].

Next, we process node B. This marks the distance to C as 6 (B is at distance 5, plus the 1 from the edge), then enqueues C into the queue. The queue is now [E, C].

Next, we process node E. This marks the distance to F as 2 (E is at distance 1, plus the 1 from the edge), then enqueues F. The queue is now [C, F].

Next, we process node C. This marks the distance to D as 7 (C is at distance 6, plus the 1 from the edge), then enqueues D. The queue is now [F, D].

Next, we process node F. This marks the distance to B as 3 (F is at distance 2, plus the 1 from the edge), then enqueues B. The queue is now [D, B].

Next, we process node D. This has no effect. The queue is now [B].

Next, we process node B. This changes the distance of node C to be 4 (B is at distance 3, plus the 1 from the edge). However, the queue is not updated, since B has already been processed.

At this point, we're done. But notice that the distance to D is wrong - we set D to be at distance seven, but the real distance is five. Why is this? It's because when we revisited B along the path A -> E -> F -> B of distance 3, we'd already processed B assuming its distance was 5, and now that we've realized that the distance to B is lower we don't get a chance to follow all the paths from B again to see what happens. We do update C, which is immediately adjacent to it, but not D, which isn't adjacent to B.

Dijkstra's algorithm avoids this by not expanding out C until it has finished looking at the path from A -> E -> F -> B and realizing that the original guess on C was incorrect. That's why it's important to process nodes in order of the estimated cost rather than in a regular breadth-first order.

Comment: I agree, however, the algorithm produced the correct response {'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 4, 'D': 5, 'E': 1, 'F': 2}

Comment: There's a minimal error, after the second step, the queue is [E,C] not [E,D]

Comment: Without some time delay or other thread exception, can anyone think of a counter example, where this would fail. I would really appreciate this. So far all the examples I tried with longer edges and smaller weights and shorter edges with heavier weights produced the correct response.

Comment: @RexAex The algorithm *can* produce the right answer if it happens to expand out the nodes in the right order. But this trace shows how it isn't guaranteed to.

Comment: @RexAex Your algorithm does process each edge in both directions. Thus when you expand the node `B` from this example, you are putting also `A` and `F` back on the queue. Dijkstra doesn't do this. This may help finding the shortest path, but of course dramatically increases the runtime complexity of your algorithm. See my expanded answer below for details. If you stop adding the "reverse direction" to the queue, the path from A to D will have weight 7